# Execute command on local machine from docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have docker container which is listening for connections and executing `iptables` rules on the actual host machine.

How can I run the command from the docker container to take effect on the actual host.

Eg:

```
Host-A (Ubuntu)
      -> Docker (docker-machine)
           -> my-container (alpine)
```

From the example about - I want to run `iptables` command in `my-container` to be applied on `Host-A`.